# Is dyn:evaluate extension function known to have issues in Xalan-J 2.7.1?

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xalan, exslt

I'm stumped as to why the following example program refuses to apply my stylesheet properly. It seems that `dyn:evaluate` in Xalan 2.7.1 is refusing to process certain XPath variables.

Running the following program with `xalan-j` in classpath yields the following results:

```java
package com.testing2.xslt;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class DynEvaluateTransform {

    private static final String XSLT = "" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"\n" +
"    xmlns:det=\"org:example:DynEvaluateTransform\"\n" +
"    xmlns:dyn=\"http://exslt.org/dynamic\"\n" +
"    extension-element-prefixes=\"dyn\"\n" +
"    version=\"1.0\">\n" +
"    \n" +
"    <xsl:variable name=\"input-doc\" select=\"document('input.xml', /)\" />\n" +
"    <xsl:variable name=\"selections\" select=\"$input-doc/det:selections\" />\n" +
"    \n" +
"    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\n" +
"        <xsl:choose>\n" +
"            <xsl:when test=\"function-available('dyn:evaluate')\">\n" +
"                <xsl:message>dyn:evaluate available</xsl:message>\n" +
"            </xsl:when>\n" +
"            <xsl:otherwise>\n" +
"                <xsl:message>dyn:evaluate not available</xsl:message>\n" +
"            </xsl:otherwise>\n" +
"        </xsl:choose>\n" +
"        <xsl:message>input.xml content:</xsl:message>\n" +
"        <xsl:for-each select=\"$selections/*\">\n" +
"            <xsl:message>{<xsl:value-of select=\"namespace-uri()\"/>}<xsl:value-of select=\"local-name()\"/></xsl:message>\n" +
"        </xsl:for-each>        \n" +
"        <xsl:for-each select=\"//@condition\">\n" +
"            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/></xsl:message>\n" +
"            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select=\"string(dyn:evaluate(string(.)))\"/></xsl:message>\n" +
"        </xsl:for-each>\n" +
"    </xsl:template>\n" +
"    \n" +
"</xsl:stylesheet>";

    private static final String EXAMPLE = "" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
"<foos xmlns=\"org:example:DynEvaluateTransform\">    \n" +
"    <foo condition=\"true()\" />    \n" +
"    <foo condition=\"false()\" />    \n" +
"    <foo condition=\"false() or true()\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections/*\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections/*[local-name()='a']\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections/element::node()[local-name()='a']\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"local-name($selections/*)\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"$selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']\" />\n" +
"    <foo condition=\"not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']) or ($selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'] and $selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])\" />\n" +
"</foos>";

    private static final String INPUT = "" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
"<selections xmlns=\"org:example:DynEvaluateTransform\">\n" +
"    <a xmlns=\"org:example:foo\"/>\n" +
"    <b xmlns=\"org:example:foo\"/>\n" +
"    <c xmlns=\"org:example:foo\"/>\n" +
"</selections>";

    private TransformerFactory xalanTransFact;    

    public DynEvaluateTransform() {
        xalanTransFact = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        xalanTransFact.setURIResolver(new Resolver());
    }

    private void applyTransform() {
        // XSLT(EXAMPLE) --> output.xml
        //         ^
        //         |
        //       INPUT
        OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

        try {
            String outputFileName = DynEvaluateTransform.getLocalFileName("output.xml");

            File file = new File(outputFileName);
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");

            System.out.println(org.apache.xalan.Version.getVersion());

            Transformer transformer = xalanTransFact.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSLT)));
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");

            transformer.transform(
                    new StreamSource(new StringReader(EXAMPLE)),
                    new StreamResult(writer));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void rebuildInput() {
        // ignore - this just writes the input.xml file, so we can later reference it
        StringReader strReader = null;
        OutputStreamWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            String fileName = getLocalFileName("input.xml");

            strReader = new StringReader(INPUT);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

            transformer.transform(
                    new StreamSource(strReader),
                    new StreamResult(fileWriter));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DynEvaluateTransform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (strReader != null) {
                strReader.close();
            }
            if (fileWriter != null) {
                try {
                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynEvaluateTransform det = new DynEvaluateTransform();
        det.rebuildInput();
        det.applyTransform();
    }   

    private static String getLocalFileName(String href) {
        String name = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        if (!name.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            name += File.separator;
        }
        name += href;
        return name;
    }

    private static class Resolver implements URIResolver {

        @Override
        public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
            if ("input.xml".equals(href)) {                
                return new StreamSource(new File(DynEvaluateTransform.getLocalFileName(href)));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Xalan Java 2.7.1
SystemId Unknown; Line #14; Column #30; dyn:evaluate available
SystemId Unknown; Line #20; Column #22; input.xml content:
SystemId Unknown; Line #22; Column #26; {org:example:foo}a
SystemId Unknown; Line #22; Column #26; {org:example:foo}b
SystemId Unknown; Line #22; Column #26; {org:example:foo}c
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; true()
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; true
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; false()
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; false
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; false() or true()
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; true
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections/*
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections/*[local-name()='a']
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections/element::node()[local-name()='a']
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; local-name($selections/*)
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; true
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; $selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; 
SystemId Unknown; Line #25; Column #26; not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']) or ($selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'] and $selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])
SystemId Unknown; Line #26; Column #26; true
```

The example program transforms an example input (EXAMPLE) using the provided transformation (XSLT), which takes an input file (INPUT, `input.xml`), opened via `document()` function, as an "argument". This input file contains a set of elements that are tested with XPath expressions (located in EXAMPLE).

The output from the program indicates that the `dyn:evaluate` function is supported, that `input.xml` is properly read, that simple XPath expressions are evaluated properly, but as soon as an XPath variable is involved it breaks.

Readable versions of all documents involved below.

input.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selections xmlns="org:example:DynEvaluateTransform">
    <a xmlns="org:example:foo"/>
    <b xmlns="org:example:foo"/>
    <c xmlns="org:example:foo"/>
</selections>
```

EXAMPLE

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foos xmlns="org:example:DynEvaluateTransform">    
    <foo condition="true()" />    
    <foo condition="false()" />    
    <foo condition="false() or true()" />
    <foo condition="$selections" />
    <foo condition="$selections/*" />
    <foo condition="$selections/*[local-name()='a']" />
    <foo condition="$selections/element::node()[local-name()='a']" />
    <foo condition="local-name($selections/*)" />
    <foo condition="not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])" />
    <foo condition="$selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']" />
    <foo condition="$selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']" />
    <foo condition="not($selections/*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo']) or ($selections/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'] and $selections/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='org:example:foo'])" />
</foos>
```

XSLT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:det="org:example:DynEvaluateTransform"
    xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
    extension-element-prefixes="dyn"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="input-doc" select="document('input.xml', /)" />
    <xsl:variable name="selections" select="$input-doc/det:selections" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="function-available('dyn:evaluate')">
                <xsl:message>dyn:evaluate available</xsl:message>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message>dyn:evaluate not available</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:message>input.xml content:</xsl:message>
        <xsl:for-each select="$selections/*">
            <xsl:message>{<xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>}<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:message>
        </xsl:for-each>        
        <xsl:for-each select="//@condition">
            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:message>
            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="string(dyn:evaluate(string(.)))"/></xsl:message>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does Xalan not support XPath variables in a `dyn:evaluate` argument? Am I defining the expressions properly? Trying to run this stylesheet in oXygen with Xalan selected, reports `java.lang.RuntimeException: ElemTemplateElement error: Function not supported!` when an XPath variable is first encountered.

Edit:

I have rewritten the question in order to clarify what my actual problem is.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You can test if your processor supports a function by using the `function-available()` function. If the function is supported, and you're getting results that differ from what you expect, then please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @michael, this is a reproducible example. Just run the code with xalan-j in classpath. The evaluate function is supported and function-available returns True for it. It is however not evaluating expressions properly. Please let me know how I can clear your confusion.

Comment: What happens if you use `org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` instead of `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl`? Xalan has two XSLT 1.0 implementations so perhaps oXygen uses the xsltc processor.

Comment: @Martin, xsltc has no support for extension functions as far as I know. Will try anyway, when able.

Comment: It seems you are right as far as `dyn:evaluate` is concerned in Xalan, so sorry about that suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked that your `document('input.xml', /)` really loads the right file when your code reads in the XSLT from a string? I see that there is code to set up a resolver but that part is where I would look first, whether the XSLT has the secondary input as intended.

Comment: @Martin, it does. In a previous step (which I removed for brevity) I xsl:message-ed the contents of the `input.xml` file. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As feared, result tree fragments in XPath variables do not appear to be supported by `dyn:evaluate` in Xalan 2.7.1. Note that variables with non- result tree fragment values work.

I wrote my own extension function (`dyn:evaluate` equivalent) that evaluates XPath expressions but it also failed to process the result tree fragment in a variable (received `this method is not yet supported` exceptions). This may be a limitation of the XPath engine implementation provided by JAXP.

Perhaps it would work with a different XPath engine implementation.

I gave up on trying to make this work and will avoid filling result tree fragments into XPath variables when `dyn:evaluate` is in play. I will simply provide information needed to evaluate my conditions through an `xsl:param` string value instead of going the hard way of using an external XML file. An extension function to Xalan will check whether a selection is actually present or not.