# Are there limitiations of <xsl:param> for passing parameters to a stylesheet one should be aware of?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parameter-passing, xslt-1.0

I need to supply an XSLT stylesheet with an argument that may contain a varying amount of data determined at runtime. I'm attempting to get a varying amount of unique QNames to the stylesheet, which are then referenced during evaluation of XPath strings. My initial attempt was to provide this data as a separate XML document, then use the `document()` function to access its content via an `<xsl:variable>`. This however proved to be troublesome in my case.

Since I'm relying on the painful 1.0 version of the stylesheet and need to evaluate string values as XPath expressions using `dyn:evaluate` exslt function, which refuses to process result tree fragments inside XPath variables (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809435/is-dynevaluate-extension-function-known-to-have-issues-in-xalan-j-2-7-1)), I've decided to supply the argument to the stylesheet as a space separated string of values via an `<xsl:param>`, where each value is a qualified name in Clark notation, such as `{org:example:foo}name`.

This solution works, however I'm concerned about using `<xsl:param>` for something like this. Should `<xsl:param>` be abused in the manner described above? Are there any limitations one should be aware of while doing this, such as length constraints?

Comment: As it is now, your question is a bit too broad, or let's say undirected. Why do you assume there would be such a shortcoming of `xsl:param`? Did any of your experiments with it fail or did you notice any problem?

Comment: @MathiasMüller, no. None of my test cases failed so far, but that does not mean they cannot. I'm only assuming there must be limitations. Or would implementations such as Xalan simply process any string that fits into RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you're using Java and Xalan. Since you're asking about limitations, the answer is going to be specific to the product you are using, so you really need to specify that in the question.

There will be restrictions on what data type you can pass to xsl:param, but it looks as if you are already working around that by encoding the data into a single string, and every processor is likely to accept string values with no trouble.

As to the length of a string, it's very unlikely that any Java processor would imposes a limit shorter than the maximum length of a Java string, which is something like 2^31 characters, and you'll probably run out of memory before you hit that limit.

Comment: So there's nothing unusual about passing a large string to a stylesheet. Works for me. And thanks for implying that types other than strings may be passed to a processor. Was not aware of that. Yes, I'm using Java/Xalan, but I wanted a generic answer, which seems to be "implementation and platform specific, not usually limited except by system resources".