# EXSLT dyn:evaluate with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan, exslt

In my XSLT transformation, I load in a different document using the document() function. When I dynamically query that document using the EXSLT dyn:evaluate() function, it only works on tags without namespaces.

The loaded XML document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:ctm="http://www.michielmeulendijk.nl/custom">
  <nativeNamespace>1</nativeNamespace>
  <ctm:externalNamespace>2</ctm:customNamespace1>
</root>
```

In the XSLT transformation, I load it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="xml-doc">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('complex-sample.xml')/*"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I query it with the EXSLT extensions:

```
<xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('exsl:node-set($xml-doc)//nativeNamespace')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:message>
<xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('exsl:node-set($xml-doc)//ctm:externalNamespace')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:message>
```

Remarkably, the result of the first query is provided correctly ('1'), but the second one's result is empty.

Comment: There is no `externalNamespace` element in the document.

Comment: Can you show a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem? Posting XSLT code using a namespace prefix without showing us the namespace declaration in the XSLT is rather pointless.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should have been externalNamespace instead of customNamespace.

Comment: I'll start preparing a complete sample.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. If I fix the mismatch between `<ctm:externalNamespace>` and `</ctm:customNamespace1>`, and make sure that the stylesheet has a namespace declaration binding the `ctm` prefix to the same namespace URI as in the source XML, I get `2` as the result of the second call. This is using libxslt.

Comment: I see. I too have added my custom namespace to the XSLT stylesheet and than it works as expected. However, I do not always know which external document my stylesheet is loading through the document() function. So could I dynamically add namespaces from the loaded document to my XSLT stylesheet...?

Comment: If you don't know which document you're dealing with, then how can you process it at all? Namespaces are part of the schema - same as element names and their hierarchy.

Comment: Well, I get the structure I want to traverse from the XSD schema directly. I'm the author of this project: https://github.com/MichielCM/xsd2html2xml. I use an XSD schema to generate an HTML form through XSLT. I want users to be able to add any corresponding XML document to fill in the form with default values. So the namespace is referenced in both the XSD and the loaded-in XML document, but not in the XSLT stylesheet. I can generate the queries from the XSD schema, however.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite follow that (and I suspect there's very little chance it can be explained to me in this space).

Answer (score -1):

It could be this bug/limitation in Xalan's implementation of dyn:evaluate:

[Is dyn:evaluate extension function known to have issues in Xalan-J 2.7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809435/is-dynevaluate-extension-function-known-to-have-issues-in-xalan-j-2-7-1?rq=1)

Why are you using Xalan anyway? It hasn't been upgraded for ten years. Switch to Saxon, and then you can use XSLT 3.0 `xsl:evaluate`, which is much more comprehensive than `dyn:evaluate`.

Although if it is the bug that I cited, you can work around it by not using a result tree fragment. Replace

```
<xsl:variable name="xml-doc">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('complex-sample.xml')/*"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

by

```
<xsl:variable name="xml-doc" select="document('complex-sample.xml')/*"/>
```

I can't think of any possible reason you would want to copy the document rather than using it directly.

Comment: "*It could be this bug/limitation in Xalan's implementation of dyn:evaluate*" No, it couldn't. Read the comments: it works just fine, once you add the namespace declaration.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You said you were using libxslt, not Xalan.

Comment: Right. And OP said they too got it working after adding the namespace declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258695/exslt-dynevaluate-with-namespace/45262699?noredirect=1#comment77481833_45258695

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it was caused indeed by omitting the namespace declaration in the XSLT stylesheet. I found that querying like this: //*[name() = 'ctm:exernalNamespace'] does work on separately loaded documents.

Comment: @MichielMeulendijk, but all those uses of `exsl:node-set($xml-doc)` in your code can indeed be completely avoided by simply using `<xsl:variable name="xml-doc" select="document('complex-sample.xml')/*"/>`, as Michael Kay suggested. That way you never create a result tree fragment in the first place and then never need to convert it to a node-set before using XPath on it, you directly have nodes from the parsed input.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I ended up using copy-of for my document() variable. However, when I use the solution to my problem like this, it no longer works: dyn:evaluate('$xml-doc//*[name() = &quot;ctm:externalNamespace&quot;]. With the copy-of variable and node-set it does work: dyn:evaluate('exsl:node-set($xml-doc)//*[name() = &quot;ctm:externalNamespace&quot;]').